# Regex to mactch a postal code and first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to match a postal code like this : H2L 3P3.

```
/^([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])\s*([0-9][A-Z][0-9])$/i.test(data)
```

How can I match this regex to check if the first character starts with `H`, `J`, `K`, `L` or `M` ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying the range `A-Z`, you can just enumerate the characters that are allowed as the first character:

```
/^([HJKLM][0-9][A-Z])\s*([0-9][A-Z][0-9])$/i
```